# AWS CLI get APIGateway returns only REST API's

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cli

The command `aws apigateway get-rest-apis` returns only `REST API's`. As you can see in the following screenshot I have 3 API's. But the command returns only one API (the REST protocol API).

How to get all 3 API's?

[image]

`aws apigateway get-rest-apis`

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "xxxxxxxx",
            "name": "zabbixPy-API",
            "description": "Created by AWS Lambda",
            "createdDate": "2021-10-31T10:16:23+00:00",
            "apiKeySource": "HEADER",
            "endpointConfiguration": {
                "types": [
                    "REGIONAL"
                ]
            },
            "disableExecuteApiEndpoint": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For HTTP api you have to use [apigatewayv2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigatewayv2/index.html):

```
aws apigatewayv2 get-apis
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the endpoint and protocol listed with version 1? `aws apigateway get-rest-apis`

Comment: @John Thanks. Not sure. You could make new question for that.